# PHP XML Simple Load

Tags: php, jquery, xml, lightbox

I have a light box currently working  www.idgc.ca/web-design-samples.php but when I converted the whole page in a Simple XML www.idgc.ca/web-design-samples-testing.php it stopped working....

Comment: You need to provide some code samples and/or more detail before anyone can help you fix this.  If you don't, it's likely this question will be closed.

Comment: Looks like errant double-quote characters are getting injected in the image URLs your lightbox is requesting.

e.g., instead of http://www.idgc.ca/images/web-design-samples/big/web-design-sample-12.jpg it's requesting http://www.idgc.ca/images/web-design-samples/big/web-design-sample-12.jpg%22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second example there is whitespace between the `<a>` and the `<img>` tags, lightbox might be looking for the first child of the `<a>` in order to get the image URL, which (in the second example) is a text node not an image tag.

This is just a guess.